# Fused disconnect for 3 motors

Tags: motor

I want to know one thing about a fused disconnect. If it's fused for a certain amount of current, would you be ok with not adding additional fuses to protect your loads?

If you have a 30 A fused disconnect and you have 2-5 hp motors and 1-3 hp motor it sounds to me like you might need to add fuses to protect each motor?

I know that for my application since my hp total is less then the 20 hp max that you can have for that disconnect at 480 V. I'm not in any trouble of tripping that breaker.

But would the motors need fusing still?

Comment: yes. each motor needs thermal overload breaker adjusted to match motor nominal curent.

Comment: So you dont need to add fuses to protect the motors individually?

Comment: I would basically add 3 6A fuses for the 3hp motor and 3 10A fuses for each of the 5hp motors. So they are protected in the already protected disconnect.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide 3 types of basic protection for EACH motor circuit:

1. Short Circuit Protection, also known as "instantaneous" protection. This is often required to be within a certain size range of the device current rating per local codes (we don't know where you are).
2. Over current protection. Different from Short Circuit protection, this is a slower increase in current. Often called "thermal protection". Again, often specified to be within a particular range, usually narrower than the SC protection. For motors in particular this is often better accomplished with what's called an "Over Load Relay".
3. Disconnecting means. A way to isolate and de-energize a circuit.

Fuses can provide #1 and #2, but you need a switch for #3. A Circuit Breaker can provide all 3 functions. But if you have a motor starter or VFD, #2 is likely part of the system already, so the fuse or breaker only needs to handle #1 and #3 (in the case of a fused disconnect).

So if you have 3 motors on one feeder circuit, the only way you can use only one set of fuses is if the rating of those fuses fits within the acceptable protection range of the SMALLEST motor, while still allowing all 3 to operate (if that's something that can happen). That is something that is difficult to arrange. IF the system includes motor starters or VFDs that have OL relays, then it becomes a little bit easier to find that range, because as mentioned the range for ONLY the SC protection is often wider.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fuse twice. The main 30A is not needed /or/ it is needed at the remote side where the wires come from. Placement position of the fuse is very simple using a rule: Wherever the wire crossection is reduced there shall be a fuse.

Supposing you have a large crossection, then you want to feed two motors at remote side. Put a fuse regarding the crossection of the wires you will install to the remote side. Then each motor is fed with yet thiner wire, add fuse.

The motor is best protected with thermal overload circuit breaker, but in some countries with fuses. For example, 3RV 2011-1JA10 is the motor protection device made from Siemens for 3HP motor @ 3ph 200VAC network. The equivalent fuse is J class 20A.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQjjtz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the wires marked as thick and thinner are the same cross section, then the fuses 1-3 are ommited.